# Bullet not traveling correct way?

Tags: java, trigonometry

I've spent a pretty long time trying to figure out how to move a bullet based on an angle (In degrees)

I define radians as:

```
public static double toRadians(int angle) {
        return (90.0 - angle) * (Math.PI / 180);
    }
```

Here is the code where I actually move the bullet.  xMov and yMov can be negative and are added onto the current position every tick.

I've never really worked with Radians, but found the above code to make 0 north, 90 east, etc, which is what I want.  I just can't figure out why the bullet isn't going to correct direction.  It appears that the X is correct but the Y isn't.

```
double x= Math.cos(Utilities.toRadians(mvmtAngle));
double y= Math.sin(Utilities.toRadians(mvmtAngle));
xMov += x* 4;
yMov += y* 4;
```

Thanks!
- tips

EDIT: The degree is being set fine (From the input)

EDIT 2:
Rendering code:

```
((Graphics2D)g).rotate(Utilities.toRadians(barrelAngle), xStart, yStart);
g.fillRect(xStart - 1, yStart, 2, BARREL_SIZE);
((Graphics2D)g).rotate(-(Utilities.toRadians(barrelAngle)), xStart, yStart);
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what "correct" is and what it's doing now.

Comment: Check my comments to the first answer, sorry about that.  I'm not the best at explaining :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that the +y direction on the screen is down, while I suspect that you want +y to be up. Your `toRadians` function converts 0 degrees to PI/2 radians, which on the screen is going down. Try using this conversion instead:

```
public static double toRadians(int angle) {
    return (angle - 90.0) * (Math.PI / 180);
}
```

This just reverses the sign of the angle. Since `Math.cos` is an even function, it won't affect the computed `x` coordinate but will reverse the sense of the `y` coordinate.

Comment: Just tried that, still not working.  Let me try and give some more info.

When I started the game, the angle is set to 0.  It is drawn facing the right.  When I fire a bullet facing the right, the bullet goes up.  When I fire it facing up, the bullet goes left, etc, etc.

Hopefully that helps.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm about to update my answer with how I render the barrel incase that's important.

Comment: @Tips48 - Okay, since you're also using `toRadians` for other purposes, leave it alone. I suggest instead that you use `double y= -Math.sin(Utilities.toRadians(mvmtAngle));`. If that doesn't work, it would be very helpful if you elaborated on exactly what's wrong with the Y movement.

Comment: I fixed it!
Turns out I had the sin and cos switched.  I think I switched them on accident but don't remember why.  Also, you were right about the sin having to be negative.
Thanks!